# Anyone tried accessing shared path on VM from Azure Function ? Putting both the same VNET did not helped

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to read the data from azure VM data disk (shared drive) via Function App, both are in the same Vnet. But still getting Access Denied Error.

Comment: Did you setup the vnet integration with function app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet.

Comment: Yes, that did not worked. Finally I am leveraging Enterprise Data Gateway and Logic App for my project requirements.

Comment: @user15428551 did u manage to fix this? I am stuck in the same boat!